# Can “Use this instead” be translated with “plutôt”?

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage

> Use this instead.

Does plutôt match the meaning of instead in this context ? I.e.

> Utilise ça plutôt.

Comment: Note que, pour ma part (mais ce n'est qu'une question de goût), je préfère changer l'ordre : *Utilise plutôt ça*

Comment: @aCOSwt  À noter que *Utilise plutôt ça* n'a qu'un sens phonétique alors que *Utilise ça plutôt* qui est rarement utilisé en français peut être phonétiquement semblable à *Utilise ça plus tôt*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

« **Plutôt** » et « **à la place** » déjà cités correspondent bien à *instead*. En revanche, *to use* est un verbe très courant en anglais alors qu'**utiliser** est peut-être un peu lourd ici. « **Prendre** » ou « **mettre** » me semblent plus idiomatiques; je suggérerais donc suivant le sens :

> « Prend plutôt ça » ou « Met plutôt ça »

ou

> « Prend ça à la place » ou « Met ça à la place »

Note: quasiment personne ne dit *cela* plutôt que *ça* en français parlé.

*Prend ça plutôt* n'est pas très idiomatique, sauf s'il y a une pause avant *plutôt*.

À l'inverse, *à la place* est idiomatique après *ça* mais pas avant.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think *plutôt* translates *instead* in your example.

*Prends plutôt ça* I would translate as *You should rather use that*.

Let me put things in context.  Say, you're at a restaurant with a friend and want to order :

> You - Tu prends quoi?
>
> Your friend - Je vais prendre une viande.  Et toi ?
>
> You -  Moi, je vais plutôt prendre du poisson.
>
> Le serveur - On n'a plus de poisson malheureusement.
>
> You - Alors, je vais prendre du canard à la place.

To me, *à la place* means you have to replace something that's not available any more, whereas *plutôt* implies that you can choose between various things that are available.

We can also have *Prends plutôt ça à la place*, meaning *You should rather use that instead*.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @aCOSwt comments here is a small answer:

> Use this instead.

may be interpreted as either

> Utilise plutôt ça (cela) / Utilise ça (cela) plutôt.

or

> Utilise à la place ça (cela) / Utilise ça (cela) à la place.

Further examples of translation are provided below

https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/instead

Comment: I don't think you can have "Utillise à la place ça", "à la place" needs to go to the end of the sentence : "utilise ça à la place".